# Windows.Forms.WebBrowser loading page with local SVG file

Tags: javascript, c#, html, svg, webbrowser-control

I have an HTML page  that generating in C# project. it works, when I open this page in IE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=10' />
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title>TemplateSVG</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='InterfaceSVG.js'></script>
</head>
<body style='margin: 0; overflow: hidden;'>
    <div class="page-content">
        <object id='idSVG'  type='image/svg+xml' data='D:\Examples\ExampleFla.svg'></object>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I loaded getting text in Web browser

```
    if (webBrowser.Document == null)
    {
        webBrowser.DocumentText = theHTMLtext;
    }
    else
    {
        webBrowser.Document.OpenNew(true);
        webBrowser.DocumentText = theHTMLtext;
    }
```

But file *InterfaceSVG.js* isn't find.

When I give full Path to js file `src='D:\[Path]\InterfaceSVG.js'`
JS script generate exception on line with `getSVGDocument()`.

```html
var SvgDoc;
window.addEventListener('load', function () {  
    SvgDoc = document.getElementById("idSVG");
    if (SvgDoc == null) { alert("error"); return; }
    SvgDoc = SvgDoc.getSVGDocument(); // IE created Access Deny.
});
```

**Edit**:
Try to insert text from js file.

```
<script>Text from InterfaceSVG.js </scipt>
```

But it generates the same exception (*Access Deny*) on line with `getSVGDocument()`

I saved result HTML page in a folder with SVG file and use function `Navigate`instead of `DocumentText`. Now it works...  but I don't want to write on disk anything.

```
    string path =  Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToSvgFile);
    string file = "\\"+Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathToSvgFile);
    string newfile = path + file;
    File.WriteAllText(newfile, theHTMLtext);
    webBrowser.Navigate(newfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how need to open a user Page.

1. Create template HTML page without scripts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=10' />
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title>Empty Page</title>
</head>
<body style='margin: 0; overflow: hidden; '>
    <div class="page-content">
        <object id='idSVG' style='height: 100%; width: 100%;  position:absolute;' type='image/svg+xml' data='{0}'></object>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Add script files and change text body of HTML page what you need  in event  webBrowser.Navigated.

   ```
       static string PathToSvgFile;
       public static void OpenSVG(this WebBrowser webBrowser, string pathToSvgFile)
       {
           if (webBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete || webBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Uninitialized)
           {
               webBrowser.Navigate([Path to emptyPage.html]);
               PathToSvgFile = pathToSvgFile;
               webBrowser.Navigated += webBrowser_Navigated;
           } 
       }

       private static void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
       {
           var webBrowser = ((WebBrowser)sender);
           HtmlElementCollection head = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head");

           if (head != null)
           {
               var element = webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
               element.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
               var elementDom = (MSHTML.IHTMLScriptElement)element.DomElement;
               elementDom.src = [JavaScriptFile.js];
               ((HtmlElement)head[0]).AppendChild(element);
           }

           webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml = String.Format(webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml, PathToSvgFile);
           webBrowser.Navigated -= webBrowser_Navigated; 
       }
   ```